# The translation map between elliptic curves is a rational map

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves

I want to see a reference or a prove that the following map is a rational map:

Let E be an elliptic curve,$P\in E$ and $T_p$ defined as

$T_p:E\rightarrow E,\text{ }T_P(Q)=P+Q$.

It is important that the prove based on the definition of rational maps. See [here](http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.783/LectureNotes5.pdf) for example.

Thanks.

Comment: Just write out the definition of addition on $E$. Or are you looking for a construction of addition on $E$ by Riemann-Roch, as in Silverman?

Comment: Elliptic curves are projective.

Comment: @Epsilondelta In that case, you can use locality of the definition of rational functions. Namely, we can conclude it is rational in a neighborhood of the origin, so that we are only let to consider a finite number of points, but we must have that $E-S \times E-S\to E$ is surjective, since $E-S$ doesnt have enough automorphisms, so that, since $T_{a+b}=T_aT_b$ finishes the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $+$ is a rational map $E \times E \to E$, and this map is the restriction of $+$ to $E \times \{P\}$, it is a rational map.